# Go обработка данных в результате выполнения MySql запроса с join?

Tags: mysql, golang, join, golang-struct

Как инициализировать и обрабатывать данные в результате выполнения запроса с join?

Например:

```
type User struct {
    Id uint
    Name string
}

type Post struct {
    Id uint
    Tittle string
    UserId uint
}

func GetAllPosts() {
    var query = `
        SELECT post.*, user.* FROM post 
        INNER JOIN user ON post.user_id = user.user_id`
    rows, err := db.Query(query)
   // как вы сохраняете и возвращаете данные такого рода?!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как то так:

```
type User struct {
    Id uint
    Name string
}

type Post struct {
    Id uint
    Tittle string
    UserId uint
}

type BlogPost struct {
    User 
    Post 
}

func GetAllPosts() {
    var query = `
        SELECT post.*, user.* FROM post 
        INNER JOIN user ON post.user_id = user.user_id`
    rows, err := db.Query(query)
    defer rows.Close()
    var posts []*BlogPost
    for rows.Next() {
        var b = &BlogPost{}
        if err := rows.StructScan(b);
        err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        posts = append(posts, b)
    }

    for _, b := range posts {
        fmt.Printf("%v", b)
    }
}
```